# Number of unique permutation of 5 letters choose 3.

Tags: combinatorics

> Given $5$ (not necessary equal) letters, find the number of all distinct $3$-tuples that can be obtained by picking $3$ out of these $5$ letters.

**Examples:**

**Case 1**

A B C D E,  5 P 3 = 60 Ways

**Case 2**

A B C D D,  33 Ways

**Case 3**

A B B C C, 18 Ways

**Case 4**

A B C C C, 13 Ways

**Case 5**

A B B B B, 4 Ways `Set { 'A-B-B', 'B-A-B', 'B-B-A', 'B-B-B' }`

**Case 6**

A A A A A, 1 Way

I wrote a simple program to brute-for count these scenario. But mathematically I cannot find a formula, reasoning to get to these answers. What are the mathematical term/formula for these kind of questions?

Comment: What is exactly the question? Why does Case 5 have 4 "ways"? Are you trying to count ABBBB, BABBB, BBABB, BBBAB, BBBBA. If so, that is 5 permutations. If not, please explain.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I added the example for case 5, does this clear things up?

Comment: So for every spot (out of 3) you have 5 options? isnt it $5^3$?

Comment: First you perform 5 P 3 which is 60 combinations, then you take only distinct way

Comment: OK, now I understand the question

Comment: @pendermath thank you, sorry I couldn't be clearer

Comment: Is the answer provided satisfying? If so, you can upvote it.

Comment: @pendermath there is no answer right now

Comment: I have formulated the problem rigorously (hopefully getting your intent right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all these cases, it comes down to selecting three letters and finding the unique ways they can be ordered. Distinguishing between the different scenarios you described:

1. Select three letters and sort them: ${5 \choose 3} 3! = 10 \cdot 6 = 60$
2. Either use one or two Ds: ${4 \choose 3}3! + {3 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1} = 24 + 9 = 33$
3. Either use three unique letters, two Bs or two Cs: ${3 \choose 3} 3! + {2 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1} + {2 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1} = 6 + 6 + 6 = 18$
4. Either use one, two or three Cs: ${3 \choose 3} 3! + {2 \choose 1}{3 \choose 1} + 1 = 6 + 6 + 1 = 13$
5. Either use two or three Bs: ${3 \choose 1} + 1 = 4$
6. Use only As: 1

All in all, it comes down to first choosing the letters, then choosing the positions assigned to each of them. In scenario 2, for instance, we either choose three out of four unique letters and order them, or choose one of the three letters joining the two Ds, and choose the position of this letter (the two Ds then simply take the remaining two positions).

Comment: Thank you if you don't mind can you clarify case 2 further? I have trouble understanding the solution.

Comment: Consider the letters A, B, C and D only. There are ${4 \choose 3} = 4$ ways to choose three letters, which can further be ordered in $3! = 6$ ways. As such, we can generate 24 combinations of three unique letters. Now consider using both Ds. In this case, we have ${3 \choose 1} = 3$ options for the third letter (A, B or C). To order the letters A, D and D, we can first choose the position of the letter A, which can be done in ${3 \choose 1} = 3$ ways. The remaining positions can then be filled by the two Ds, resulting in ADD, DAD or DDA. As such, there are $3 \cdot 3 = 9$ combinations.

Comment: I understand now thank you!